# Using a reference to vector elements in a ranged for

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I'm trying to understand why I need to use a reference in a ranged for, to get the following expression to apply to the elements in the vector.

The code simply defines a vector and initialises some elements, then uses a ranged for to square them, and print the output.

```
int main() {
        vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5};
        for (auto &i : v1)
                i *= i;
        for (auto i : v1)
                cout << i << " ";
        cout << endl;
}
```

The above works, but if for the first ranged for I use:

```
for (auto i : v1)
```

the elements then do not get squared. What's the difference here? I don't understand the need to use a reference in this case, but not later when I want to cout each element using another ranged for.

Comment: If you are using VS, try to hover on the 'auto' and see what the deduced variable is. I would think `auto i` would read as `int i`. Basically you are squaring a local copy of the element in your vector. When adding `&`, you tell the compiler to grab a reference to the element in your vector, thus modifying the object in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put :

`for (auto i : v1)` copies the values into a new variable.

`for (auto &i : v1)` references the actual value in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 7; // i = 7
int j = i; // j = 7 (a copy of i)
j *= j; // j = 49 (but i, fortunately, is still 7)
```

And of course:

```
int i = 7; // i = 7
auto j = i; // j = 7 (a copy of i)
j *= j; // j = 49 (but i is still 7)
```

And the same happens in a range based loop:

```
for (auto i : v) // i is a copy of an element of v
    i*= i; // you square the copy of the element of v, not the element itself
```